# RequestScoped bean to be injected into a HandlerFunction

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

Below is the Route configuration to a webflux HandlerFunction. I am using Spring Cloud Config for fetching the properties. Here I have a dynamic property `originairports.shutdown` that changes frequently in the properties file, that gets injected into the `String airports` variable using `@Value("${originairports.shutdown}") String airports` whenever I give `/actuator/bus-refresh` http POST to the service. For that I have given the annotation `@RefreshScope`. I then convert the comma separated String to a List and register it as a request scoped Bean because I want a new Bean when the value changes dynamically.

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class SearchRoutes
{   
    @Value("${originairports.shutdown}")
    String airports;

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public List<String> originAirports()
    {
        logger.info("Origin Airports in shutdown " + airports);
        return Arrays.asList(airports.split(","));
    }  

@Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> search()
    {
        RouterFunction<ServerResponse> searchRoutes = RouterFunctions.route(POST("/search/get"),
                                                                            searchHandler.search);
        return searchRoutes;

    }  
}
```

Below is the Handler class code where I `@Autowire` the bean to check the value to return a response accordingly. The application boots up perfectly but when I give a request, I get the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'request'`. So what is the problem with this code?

```
@Component
public class SearchHandler
{
    @Autowired
    private List<String> originAirports;

    public HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> search = request ->
    {
        Mono<SearchQuery> searchQuery = request.bodyToMono(SearchQuery.class);

        return searchQuery.flatMap(sq ->
        {
            if (originAirports.contains(sq.getOrigin()))
            {
                logger.info("The origin airport " + sq.getOrigin() + " is in shutdown state");
                return ServerResponse.notFound()
                        .build();
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that was a silly question, but it took me a while to solve. I just created a new component, made it with Scope prototype and it's working. Here is the code.

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
@Scope("prototype")
public class RefreshComponent
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RefreshComponent.class);

    @Value("${originairports.shutdown}")
    String airports;

    public String originAirports()
    {
        logger.info("Origin Airports in shutdown " + airports);
        return new String(airports);
    }

}
```